# Get the content of a web page from an external app

Tags: java, android

Is there a way to detect if a specific URL is reached on chrome (for example) and if so get the content of the page ? I've been searching for a couple of hours but I didn't find anything about this.

Thank you !

Comment: https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/devguide

Comment: @HomeIsWhereThePcIs sorry if I was not clear but I want to do it from an android app and not from a chrome extension (furthermore there is no extension on mobile)

Answer (score 0):

Use Webview or Chrome Custom Tabs
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView
https://developer.chrome.com/multidevice/android/customtabs

Comment: Thank you ! But it's not really what I wanted. I want to get the content of a web page (in my app) when the user open the web page (in his browser).

Comment: If you could do that how safe do you think it would be to use Android :)

Comment: I'm using a Password Manager (bitwarden) and it can fill automatically the user/password for me. To do this I thought that it has to "get" the page content to detect the specific HTML tag. Am I wrong ?

Comment: @HomeIsWhereThePcIs https://i.imgur.com/24P0h64.jpg in my accessibility parameters

Comment: Password managers don't get the entire page. They get a request from an app for autofill. https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/text/autofill-services